# Delayed decision after postdoc interview

Tags: postdocs, interview

I was interviewed on 17 Nov. The interview should be 45 minutes, but it actually took one hour.  At the end of the interview, the PI promised that they will inform me the outcome in two days. But I have not received their email yet. I start to feel frustrated now. How long does it take to get response after postdoc interview?

Comment: A little patience goes a long way in these situations. Good luck :-)

Comment: Ask late on Monday if you don't get any mail, but also check your junk mail folder. Any little thing could account for a few days delay

Comment: I do not see a question.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of explanations.

Since the time is short, the most likely one is that there was a delay in getting someone's signature. This is also the most positive outcome.

But if there were several people interviewed, it might also be that you aren't the first choice, but are still in the running. Time will be required to get an answer from anyone to whom an offer is made. You probably won't know if this is the case. And you won't hear much of anything for a week at least.

If you were quickly rejected or accepted you are likely to hear sooner rather than later, though some places aren't especially good about informing those who don't get an offer.

But now, the week-end intervenes making it harder for those who need to sign-off to be contacted. The academic clock can run slow at times.